# Sum of products of column with cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, product, sumproduct

I want to multiply each cell of the column with a value defined in some range and get their sum.

- A1: 2000
- B1: 1, B2: 2, B3: 3

I expect `B1*A1 + B2*A1 + B3*A1 = 2000*1 + 2000*2 + 2000*3 = 12000`

I tried:

`=PRODUCT(B1:B3, A1)` returns A1*B1*B2*B3
`=B1:B3*A1` invalid
`=SUMPRODUCT(B1:B3, A1)` invalid, it requires the same columns

Comment: This is simplified sample. I might disinterpret the large values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this formula in any cell outside column B.

=A1*(SUM(B:B))

Comment: Factoring first makes the answer much easier to see...

Answer (score 3):

Easiest method:

```
=SUM(B1:B3)*A1
```

Or an array formula (must be entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)

```
=SUM(B1:B3*$A$1)
```